# Storing Bash associative arrays

Tags: arrays, bash, associative-array, data-retrieval, storing-information

I want to store (and retrieve, of course) Bash's associative arrays and am looking for a simple way to do that.

I know that it is possible to do it using a look over all keys:

```
for key in "${!arr[@]}"
do
  echo "$key ${arr[$key]}"
done
```

Retrieving it could also be done in a loop:

```
declare -A arr
while read key value
do
  arr[$key]=$value
done < store
```

But I also see that `set` will print a version of the array in this style:

```
arr=([key1]="value1" [key2]="value2" )
```

(Unfortunately along with all other shell variables.)

Is there a simpler way for storing and retrieving an associative array than my proposed loop?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To save to a file:

```
declare -p arr > saved.sh
```

(You can also use `typeset` instead of `declare` if you prefer.)

To load from the file:

```
source saved.sh
```